# How to add and use TCPDF in magento 2

Tags: magento2, pdf

I am adding one custom pdf functionality in my magento store, for that I want to use TCPDF but I am not able to add it. it always shows that class is not found and all. 
Can anyone tell me what is proper way to add and use tcpdf in magento 2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to run following command from M2 root directory

```
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf
```

After install, use following way to create new PDF document tcpdf

```
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me  Can you please explain me how it works ? 
Means how magento will come to know that TCPDF class is there in tecnickcom direcotry  ?

Comment: Read http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/, Magento 2 use PSR-4 for autoloading   class and TCPDF too.

Comment: I Need Without Installing via composer, let me know a solution.

Comment: Can you answer this I am having similar issue 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246155/how-to-create-custom-pdf-on-controller-action-using-tcpdf-in-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to install TCPDF without composer ;

1. Download TCPDF from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf
2. Change the name of the file root directory after extraction to TCPDF
3. Inside this directory, there is a tcpdf.php file, change the name to TCPDF
4. Open the file and change the class name from tcpdf to `TCPDF_TCPDF` , am very sure those that are really familiar with Magento will know why.
5. Copy the files into your Magento “lib” folder in the root Magento installation directory.
6. And you have successfully incorporated TCPDF with Magento, from anywhere in Magento, you can call this class by `$tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF()` .

Working tested in magento 2.1.10.

Reference - https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/using-tcpdf-with-magento.html

Comment: Can you answer this, I am having similar issue:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246155/how-to-create-custom-pdf-on-controller-action-using-tcpdf-in-magento-2

Comment: not working with magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

For that you can add `"tecnickcom/tcpdf": "*"` in your root composer file. here `tecnickcom/tcpdf` is `TCPDF` library and `*` contain the latest version of `TCPDF`. If you want to use any specific version `TCPDF` then replace with `*` with version number.

After updating the composer file you just need to run `composer update` command from magento 2 root directory. After successfully downloading `TCPDF` you can use in every place of Magento 2 like `block`,`helper` etc

here is the my composer file

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.2",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```