# How to use TCPDF in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tcpdf

I have a big problem. After I have upgraded my Shop from Magento 1 to Magento 2.1.7 I am not able to run TCPDF. 
I installed TCPDF via composer in the Vendor folder as described, but when I try to generate - even an empty pdf - nothing works.

I hope, somebody can help me.

Christian

Comment: Is it showing any error? How you are running it?

Comment: Please review below link. [How to use TCPDF in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156510/how-to-add-and-use-tcpdf-in-magento-2)

Comment: In Magento 1 I had this structur:

Comment: root
-documents

Comment: I tried this code
<?php
$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

//your htmls here
$html = '<h1> hello world </h1>';

$tcpdf->AddPage();

$tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$tcpdf->lastPage();

$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route_'.time().'.pdf', 'I');

Nothing work


I put the test.php file in the root directory of M2 and called it.

Comment: I tried to call the example file of the vendor

Comment: mysite/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/examples/examples_001.php
before I have replaced

$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
 nothing

then i tried to include the example file in a new file in the root directory, nothing