# How to create custom pdf on controller action using TCPDF in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-controller, print, invoice-pdf, tcpdf

I have added TCPDF as follows:

1. Downloaded TCPDF library from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf
   and place at `magento2.0/lib/internal/TCPDF`
2. Renamed tcpdf.php to **TCPDF.php**
3. Opened **TCPDF.php** and change class name to class **TCPDF_TCPDF**
4. Created Controller

> magento2.0/app/code/Namespace/Module_Name/Controller/Generatepdf/createpdf.php

```
<? php

namespace Namespace\Module_Name\Controller\Generatepdf;

use TCPDF_TCPDF;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Createpdf extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {

public function execute() {
$baseDir = DirectoryList::MEDIA;

$tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information

    $tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

    $tcpdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');

    $tcpdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');

    $tcpdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');

    $tcpdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');


// set default header data

    $Header_title = 'Sample PDF';

    $tcpdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE . $Header_title, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0, 64, 255), array(0, 64, 128));

    $tcpdf->setFooterData(array(0, 64, 0), array(0, 64, 128));


// set header and footer fonts

    $tcpdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

    $tcpdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


// set default monospaced font

    $tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


// set margins

    $tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

    $tcpdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

    $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


// set auto page breaks

    $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor

    $tcpdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// set some language-dependent strings (optional)

    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {

        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');

        $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    }


// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode

    $tcpdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

//your htmls here

$html = **For PDF file Write Your HTML Code here** ;

// set some language dependent data:

    $lg = Array();

    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';


    $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($lg);


// set font

//dejavusans & freesans For Indian Rupees symbol

    $tcpdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

    // remove default header/footer

//$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

    $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


    $tcpdf->AddPage();


    $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


    $tcpdf->lastPage();



//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

    $this->logger->debug('report_per_route');

    $filename = $baseurl . '/Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';

    $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'F');




}

}


? >
```

I want to understand how to add my code in above class. My required PDF should contain fileds like Order Number, Customer Name, Item Name, Item Quanity. I am getting these values in my custom template file from Order collection.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Is your sample pdf rendering?

Comment: Nothing is happeng till now

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi  Did you got a solution.? i need the same. please share your solution briefly here.

Comment: @AskBytes Yes, You can see tested solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250951/how-to-install-tcpdf-lib-without-composer-in-magento-2

Comment: is it working for you?

Comment: Check here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251287/67038  @Devidas

Comment: Thank you bro it's working

Answer (score 1):

try tp Add your data like this after setting your languages in the above code

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 12);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set some text to print
$txt = <<<EOD
TCPDF Example 003

 Custom page header and footer are defined by extending the TCPDF class     and overriding the Header() and Footer() methods.
 EOD;

 // print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

 // ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: for reference https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/

Answer (score 0):

- ### add code in composer.json

{
    "name": "xyz/module-xyz",
    "description": "XYZ",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0|~7.2.0",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf ":"*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "email": "biz@xyz.com",
            "homepage": "https://example.com/"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "xyz\Xyz\": ""
        }
    }
}

Comment: after run command 
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf