# After upgrade to Magento 2.4 include_once is not working anymore

Tags: magento2.4, phtml, require-once

I have created an extension to create custom pdf. Everything was working fine in my former magento 2.1 version. Now magento has been upgraded to version 2.4 and my phtml files dont run anymore. Within my phtml file I use require_once to call several classes that are stored in other folders.

```
require_once('lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php');
require_once('app/code/Mcas/BusinessDocuments/Block/Adminhtml/MYPDF.php');
```

This function does not work anymore. I get the error, that these file do not exits.
When I try include instead of require_once I get this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: include(/html/magento2/app/code/Mcas/PdfOrder/view/frontend
/templateslib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php): failed to open stream:
```

I realy need help!

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I guess your 2.4 installation is now using **/pub** as document root

So, you could update all that `includes` / `requires` adding `../` at the beginning

Comment: thanks, I will try it

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

[How to add and use TCPDF in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156510/how-to-add-and-use-tcpdf-in-magento-2)

It seems as if there are better ways than require_once to get TCPDF working with Magento 2. You will need to rewrite your block to use composer but the effort will be worth it as upgrades will be easier in the future.

Comment: Sure! Working with includes and requires don't seem a nice practice

Comment: I understand, but I dont know how to use the composer